# How do I fix Import Error: DLL Load Failed in python for scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, installation, failed-installation

I recently downloaded Anaconda onto my computer to work in Python for school. Recently, I need to use scipy for the integrate function to solve an ODE. However, when I import the scipy.integrate, I get the following error:

My sample code is just one line that will not compile:

`import scipy.integrate`

And I get the error message below:

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`

The fixes I have tried so far:
1. Uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda
2. In the anaconda powershell running "conda update conda" followed by "conda update anaconda"
3. Restarting my computer.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT: The full error message is below:

```py
runfile('C:/Users/Eric/Documents/College Work/CBE5790/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Eric/Documents/College Work/CBE5790')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-61942190ad9a>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Eric/Documents/College Work/CBE5790/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/Eric/Documents/College Work/CBE5790')

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Eric/Documents/College Work/CBE5790/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    import scipy.integrate

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\__init__.py", line 93, in <module>
    from ._bvp import solve_bvp

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\integrate\_bvp.py", line 10, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import splu

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 116, in <module>
    from .eigen import *

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .arpack import *

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .arpack import *

  File "C:\Users\Eric\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\eigen\arpack\arpack.py", line 45, in <module>
    from . import _arpack

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: How did you install the module? Please share the entire error message.

Comment: See above for the complete output from the error message. I followed the instructions on the Anaconda site for downloading everything.

Comment: Are you sure that when you’re running the program the correct environment is being used?